# Problems using template to create new PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I made an upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 a few days ago. So far so good.

Now I want to use an existing Postgres template to create a new database.
The template has to schemas. In one I installed teh postgis extension.

My Problem is, that the system ignores my search_path and defeault schema setting. I tried to create a new schema, but the problem still remains.

Best regards, in hope of your ideas.
michael.

Comment: What is the exact statement you use to create the new database? Also: the `search_path` is set for each user **per** database. So if you change the search path for a user in one database, that does not mean the user has the same search_path in a different database.

Comment: I tried it using PGAdmin III and also by using the shell command :

Comment: createdb -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -E UTF8 -T template_postgis new_db

Comment: After that I also tried :   ALTER DATABASE new_db
  SET search_path = postgis_2,public;   but with no effect !